# Applications ->Configuration->Email Queue->Send email: subject field extended characters encoding issue

Tags: kentico

I'm trying to find the reason, why the email I sent via the Applications ->Configuration->Email Queue->Send email module converts all extended characters (like ěščř) to question marks. I have utf-8 and html format set in Email settings module for the website.
Please help.

Comment: Could you specify the Kentico version and what SMTP server you are using?

Comment: @simply007, I'm using kentico 11. it seems to it's not depends on smtp server, I tried with a few smtp servers including gmail. Issue is the same - the subject field doesn't encoded.

Comment: @andryi-b - I have tried the same scenario with changing the encoding ok v11.0 and also on latest hotfix - subject is still displayed as question marks.

In that case, I would point you to the [support](https://devnet.kentico.com/support).

Comment: I have tried it on version 11.0 and also on the latest hotfix and the subject is corrupted on both versions.

I would recommend [submitting the issue](https://www.kentico.com/services/technical-support/submit-support-issue) on the official support. 

I thought it is caused by setting the encoding for [email subject for the SMTP client](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4d1c1752-70ba-420a-9510-8fb4aa6da046/subject-encoding-on-smtpclientmailmessage?forum=wcf), but even when changing the encoding in settings did not help too.